# renaming file with same name as directory name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a directory structure as follows

```
dir----|
       |
       |--dir1\ some\ thing--result.pdf
       |
       |--dir2\ some\ thing--result.pdf
       |
       |--dir3\ some\ thing--result.pdf
       |
```

The file name in each subdirectory is result.pdf.

Where as directories dir1 dir2 dir3 have blank spaces in their name.
What I am not able to understand (I am writing a bash script) how do I take this directory name in variable and rename result.pdf

I want to rename each of this file result.pdf with same name as directory name.pdf

```
   #!/bin/bash
    for i in *;do
    cd $i
    mv result.pd $i.pdf
    cd ..
    done
```

blank spaces in directory names are creating problems.How to over come this?

Comment: Step 1: find . -exec rename ' ' - {} \;  Step 2: profit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to quote the names:

```
for i in *; do
  mv "$i/result.pdf" "$i/$i.pdf";
done
```

Comment: @ypons thanks your method worked but I am not yet clear as why we needed to use double quotes.

Comment: If you use the quotes, the string enclosed in them is given to 'mv' as one argument. So 'mv' knows that all of it belongs to the same filename. Otherwise, if there is a blank, it will result in two consecutive arguments to 'mv', so 'mv' treads the parts left and right of the blank as separate filenames. If you use single quotes, the stuff inside the quotes is not evaluated by the shell, so $i would not be expanded, instead it would stay $i. That's the difference between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner -

```
for i in *; do mv "$i/result.pdf" "$i/$i.pdf" ; done
```