# Rename file inside directory by its directory name

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple directories, that contain single file inside, and the file in all directories is with the same name. I need to rename the file by its directory name, so that I can collect them in the same directory.

```
/home/x/Desktop/s0.01-k5/x      
/home/x/Desktop/s0.01-k7/x
/home/x/Desktop/s0.01-k10/x
```

What I need is to rename all the x's to their directory names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886239/renaming-file-with-same-name-as-directory-name should help, just ignore the part about white spaces

Comment: See [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629302/better-way-to-rename-files-based-on-multiple-patterns/25597051#25597051)

Answer (score 0):

Go into /home/x/Desktop. There

```
for i in */x;do mv -vf "$i" "${i%/x}/${i%/x}";done
```

This command does what you want. If you want to be sure what will hapen, you can test this by giving an "echo" for the "mv":

```
for i in */x;do echo mv -vf "$i" "${i%/x}/${i%/x}";done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> cd /home/x/Desktop/

```
for i in $(ls); do mv $i/* $i/$i; done
```

Comment: [Do not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
Also you have to quote every parameter.